# How does addition assignment operator behave

Tags: c#, asp.net, csharpcodeprovider

How does addition assignment operator behaves here -

```
btn.Click += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Comment: i understand that x+= y means x = x + y, but what with the events

Comment: this is how you assign an event handler to btn.click event in c#

Comment: refer to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx for more details

Comment: This is what I typed in Google "c sharp += delegate" and what I have got under the second link [C# - Delegates](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_delegates.htm) in section: "Multicasting of a Delegate" - _Delegate objects can be composed using the "+" operator. A composed delegate calls the two delegates it was composed from. Only delegates of the same type can be composed. The "-" operator can be used to remove a component delegate from a composed delegate._ Honestly, it's pure laziness.

Comment: is it what is called anonymous method?

Comment: delegates are objects with name which must be instantiated. Their purpose is to define a sort of placeholder if you want to pass and then invoke a function e.g. inside an another method / function. A _Anonymous function_ on the other hand is a function without name, defined and instantiated inline. E.g., `TypeOutput = delegate(TypeINput variable) { // body of a function };`. The latter is superseded by Lambda Expressions from c# 3.0 onward. I cannot fully explain this in this comment, I am afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It adds an event handler to the event `Click`.
When `Click` event is raised all the handlers method added to it are called.

For example:

```
void BtnClickHandler1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("BtnClickHandler1");
}

void BtnClickHandler2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("BtnClickHandler2");
}
```

And you add these methods to Click event like this:

```
btn.Click += BtnClickHandler1
btn.Click += BtnClickHandler2
```

When button is clicked the methods will be called in the order you added them, so the message box will be:

```
BtnClickHandler1
BtnClickHandler2
```

If you want specific info about += operator, [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew.aspx) says:

> The += operator is also used to specify a method that will be called
>   in response to an event; such methods are called event handlers. The
>   use of the += operator in this context is referred to as subscribing
>   to an event.

For more info look at:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

http://www.dotnetperls.com/event

Comment: it does wire the event handler to button's click, but it seems we can write code inline here

Comment: btn.Click += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
lblResult.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
};

Comment: What you are talking about is [Anonymous Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/0yw3tz5k.aspx), but they don't depend on events